# Jquery with on Event

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to add mouse over and  mouseleave effets. Some code is coming on **document load** and some divs are **loading by ajax**

here is my code

```
                    $(".boxes").on('mouseover',function(){
                        ids = $(this).attr('vals');
                        myVar = setTimeout(function() {
                        $("." + ids).show();
                        }, 1000);                                
                            $("."+ids).css("display","block !important");
                        },function(){
                                clearTimeout(myVar);
                                $("."+ids).hide();
                        });
But this is not working 
giving me error
```

> ReferenceError: myVar is not defined. I write above code on **document ready**

How to fix this issue? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The error says it all :) var myVar perhaps? :)

Comment: `var ids = $(this).attr('vals');`& `var myVar = setTimeout(function() {` replace this

Comment: $(".boxes").on('mouseover',function(){
      ids = $(this).attr('vals');
      var myVar = setTimeout(function() {
                        $("." + ids).show();
                        }, 1000);                                
       $("."+ids).css("display","block !important");
      },function(){
        clearTimeout(myVar);
        $("."+ids).hide();
      });

Comment: have you used myVar in some other places ?

Answer (score 0):

```
myVar = 1;
$(".boxes").on('mouseover',function(){
                    ids = $(this).attr('vals');
                    myVar = setTimeout(function() {
                    $("." + ids).show();
                    }, 1000);                                
                        $("."+ids).css("display","block !important");
                    },function(){
                            clearTimeout(myVar);
                            $("."+ids).hide();
                    });
```

you have to declare myvar outside the event.. then asign it a different value